# Reusing variable names when modifying a string (PHP)

Tags: php

Is it bad form to reuse the variable name when you're manipulating a string like the example below?

```
    <?php
    $string = "Jimmy <b>likes</b> red shoes";
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = str_replace("red", "blue", $string);
    $string = strtoupper($string);
    echo $string;
    ?>
```

If it's a no-no, what is preferred?  Should one try to make it into one line of code?  Or use 4 different variable names?

I tried searching, but the only reference I could find was in regards to changing the variable from an array to a string or something like that.

Comment: I don't think this is what they mean by "don't reuse variable names". Just sayin'.

Comment: For me it's ok and it's exactly how I do this kind of statements.

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as "reusing the name" you could think of it as you're just modifying the same variable several times. And no, I'd say there's absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it, as long as you don't need the original `$string` value again later. Once you've done `$string = something($string)`, the original value is destroyed and replaced with the modified version.

In theory, you could simply chain the entire sequence together

```
echo strtoupper(str_replace('red', 'blue', strip_tags('Jimmy likes...')));
```

but that makes for unreadable and unmaintainable code.

Comment: I remember one of my hurdles learning PHP was trying to read stuff like this from the inside out. OP's version is definitely much clearer.

Comment: @Marmartigan: OP's version is much clearer. But, from this article: http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html : Don't copy variables for no reason.

Comment: @ZulkhaeryBasrul: "No reason"? The reason is readability and ease of maintenance. I can think of several other reasons but I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names should be a short, precise description of the data stored therein. Consequently, re-using a variable name is fine, even preferable when there isn't a better name. On the flip side, a variable shouldn't be re-used in a misguided attempt at [optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization):

```
for ($i=0; $i < n; ++$i) {
    ...
}
for ($map as $i => $value) {
    ...
}
```

The indices (values stored in `$i`) in the second loop better be integers, rather than re-using `$i` to store strings, because `$i` is almost universal code for an integer index. If someone insists on clearing space, they can use [`unset`](http://php.net/unset).

The real danger of variables is using them in broad scope (globals and large functions), where namespace collisions can cause data to be overwritten. In addition to preventing collisions, small functions can help reduce memory usage, as local variables will be more short lived.